# Can we add an event listener to a child component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I understand that we can pass an event listener to a child component as a prop in React. For example,

```
function Parent(){
   function handleClick(){
     console.log("click");
   }
   return (
     <Child handleClick={handleClick} />
   )
}

function Child({handleClick}){
   return (
     <button onClick={handleClick} >Child<button>
   )
}
```

Can we attach the event listener to the child component without passing the handleClick method as a prop? For example,

```
function Parent(){
       function handleClick(){
         console.log("click");
       }
       return (
         <Child onClick={handleClick} />
       )
    }
```

Comment: Nope, you have to pass it through like the first way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, it's possible to attach the event listener to the child component without passing the `handleClick` method as a prop, but you still need to pass some other prop, such as a ref, to access the child component's DOM node.

For example:

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

function Parent() {
  const childRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleCustomEvent = (event) => {
      console.log("clicked!");
    };
    childRef.current?.addEventListener("click", handleCustomEvent);
    return () => {
      childRef.current?.removeEventListener("click", handleCustomEvent);
    };
  }, []);

  return <Child forwardRef={childRef} />;
}

function Child({ forwardRef }) {
  return <button ref={forwardRef}>Child</button>;
}

export default Parent;
```

However, this approach may be less readable and less idiomatic than passing the `handleClick` method as a prop. Passing props is the recommended way of communicating data and events between components in React. Using props also makes your code more declarative and easier to test. Therefore, I think your original method is better than this alternative.